# Domain name is not resolving (Can't find: No answer)

Tags: dns, whois, nslookup

I'm having a domain yantdom.com

It has valid whois information:

> Name Server: ns1.myownns.ru
>
> Name Server: ns2.myownns.ru

And the nameserver it's stored on works fine:

> $nslookup yantdom.com ns1.myownns.ru
>
> Server:       ns1.myownns.ru
>
> Address:  46.4.55.210#53
>
> Name: yantdom.com
>
> Address: 46.4.55.210

But for some reason when I do lookup on google DNS servers I get this:

> *** Can't find yantdom.com: No answer

Same with other name servers.

Here's my zone file:

```
$TTL 3600
yantdom.com.    IN  SOA raibo.ru. konstantin.raibo.ru. (2014051400 10800 3600 604800 86400)
yantdom.com.    IN  NS  ns1.myownns.ru.
yantdom.com.    IN  NS  ns2.myownns.ru.
yantdom.com.    IN  A   46.4.55.210
www IN  A   46.4.55.210
```

Which work totally fine for other domains hosted and served on the server.

What could be possibly be wrong with this domain? Where should I look at first?

Thank you!

Comment: is `raibo.ru` your ns1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I query the NS records for the domain I get:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ dig -t ns yantdom.com +short
ns2.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com.
ns1.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com.
```

It seems you have not completed the contact verification process (additional information [here](http://www.mddhosting.com/support/knowledgebase/1021/Registrar-Accreditation-Agreement---Verification-of-WHOIS-Details.html)). I haven't seen this before, but I suggest you contact your registrar.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with my registrar (ActiveDomain (they really suck)). 
They sent me a verification email but GMail put it in the 'Spam' folder.

So, to solve your problem, open search your Junk/Spam folder for a verification email from your registrar.

Comment: We had this exact issue for one of our clients. What a lame registrar.